# Insert into database where id picked from previous activiy

Tags: android

My small app has 2 activity, the first activity contains a listview that show all id from database, each listview item uses the same second activity (the same layout). When I click each item in listview, the second layout will be showed, it has a edittext,textview and button, when I hit the button, data in edittext will be inserted into a column in database and displayed throw textview, this data must be in the same row with id, its mean that each item in listview of the first layout show the different value in second layout. How can I do this???
For more details:
My database has a table with id and name column, 
(id   name)
(1     A)
(2     B)
..    ..
When I click the one item (has id 1) in listview of first layout, the name A should be display in second layout and another item (has id 2) will show the name B in second layout and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the id from activity A to B through the bundle object.

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, B.class);
in.putExtra("id", id);
startActivity(in);
```

then get the id in Activity B

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
id = extras.getInt("id");
```

And then you will have to get the data from the database.
Another option is to pass all information through the bundle object.

Comment: :D thank you again, I have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296293/select-where-not-work?noredirect=1#comment33880451_22296293 if you have time, please help me