# "select where" not work

Tags: android, sqlite

In My DataBaseAdapter Class, I write a method getAll like that

```
public List<AllUserInfor> getAllInfor(int id) {
    List<AllUserInfor> allInfor = new ArrayList<AllUserInfor>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT Name, Gender FROM MY_TABLE where _id = '"+id+"' ";

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            AllUserInfor alluserinfor = new AllUserInfor();               
            alluserinfor.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            alluserinfor.setGender(cursor.getString(2));                
            allInfor.add(alluserinfor);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    return allInfor;
}
```

and in the second activity, I have

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btShow:
        // I get id from the first activity
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        id = extras.getInt("Roomid");
        List<AllUserInfor> userInfor = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllInfor(id);
        for (AllUserInfor aui : userInfor){
            tvname.setText(aui.getName());
            tvgender.setText(aui.getGender());

        }
        break;
    }

}
```

this is the way I get id from first activity

```
lvroom.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cursor = (Cursor) lvroom.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int item_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID));

            Intent i = new Intent();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("Roomid", item_id);               
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            i.setClass(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);

        }
```

After I hit the Show button inf second activity, nothing change, its mean that the name and gender are not showed in second layout. Where are my mistakes? Help me

this is my logcat

```
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at com.superman.medreport.SecondActivity.onClick(SecondActivity.java:127)
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-10 18:01:20.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 18:01:24.802: E/Trace(1256): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code. Consider debugging it and asking specific questions instead of just "not work" "where are my mistakes".

Comment: @laalto thanks for reminding me, this is the second time I post my question, so the mistakes are inevitable.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas yes, the LogCat said that I have error in second activity, in details: List<AllUserInfor> userInfor = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllInfor(id); do you have any idea?

Comment: Post the error from logcat

Comment: @DavidHirst I have posted the logcat, help me please!!!

Comment: Well it looks like your problem is "mySQLiteAdapter" where are you initialising this in your code?

Comment: Well, I puted it before onCreate: SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not cast your `id` value into the `String` as its an `Integer` in your table.

Change your criteria as below to get value:

```
"SELECT Name, Gender FROM MY_TABLE where _id = "+id+" ";
```

Just remove the single `" ' "` and write as `"+id+"` not `'"+id+"'`

Answer (score 2):

Is it because _id is an integer? And you are passing a string

```
 '"+id+"'
```

should be

```
  "+id+"
```

Comment: in addition you could also get away with just "SELECT Name, Gender FROM MY_TABLE where _id = "+id; Though I would suggest using parameterized queries.

Comment: I had tried two ways you suggested but I do not know why its not work

Comment: I would debug your item_id to see what is returned. It would appear that your query is perhaps receiving 0 from this variable and therefore not producing the desired result. However it is very difficult for me to comment without seeing some sort of error or your actual database structure.

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm, I use a textview to show the item_id in second activity and its work, however the selection query still not work @@!

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
"SELECT Name, Gender FROM MY_TABLE where _id ="+id+";
```

instead of

```
"SELECT Name, Gender FROM MY_TABLE where _id = '"+id+"' ";
```